# Ubuntu 14.10 wants to install along windows 8 i don't have windows 8 i have 7

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, windows-7, windows-8

Like the title says.
I boot from USB and it shows to install alongside of windows 8 the problem is I don't have windows 8 i have windows 7 Why is it telling me I have windows 8 install i only have windows 7?
Can someone tell me what I did wrong?
I install Ubuntu before on this PC and it never shows windows 8 before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Did you previously had windows 8 installed?*
In windows you can run -> `msconfig` and check what are the boot settings. Maybe you still have old boot settings, or just the name is incorrect. If so, just edit them (make sure you don't delete the correct one as it will make booting issues).

If you never had windows 8 installed, you don't have to worry about the fact it is identified as windows 8 as what's important for Grub is that the path is correct.

Comment: never had windows 8 install i try it any way it only shows i have windows 8 but boots to windows 7 thank you for helping me i change the name so it shows windows 7 now

Comment: Glad to hear :) !